# Metafunction for type conversion

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I am learning template programming by the book "C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost and Beyond" and somehow I got myself stuck at the very first exercise.

The task is to write an unary metafunction `add_const_ref<T>` that returns `T` if it is a reference type, and otherwise returns `T const &`.

My approach is:

```
template <typename T>
struct add_const_ref
{
    typedef boost::conditional
      <
        boost::is_reference<T>::value, // check if reference
        T,                             // return T if reference
        boost::add_reference           // return T const & otherwise
          <
            boost::add_const<T>::type
          >::type
      >::type
    type;
};
```

I tried to test it (I am using the Google Unit Testing Framework, hence the syntax):

```
TEST(exercise, ShouldReturnTIfReference)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(boost::is_same
      <
        int &,
        add_const_ref<int &>::type
      >::value
    );
}
```

But it does not compile:

```
main.cpp:27:5: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct boost::add_reference’
main.cpp:27:5: error:   expected a type, got ‘boost::add_const<T>::type’
main.cpp:28:4: error: template argument 3 is invalid
```

I really don't understand why `boost::add_const<T>::type` would not meet the requirement of being a type. I would appreciate a hint what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a lot of `typename`s here:

```
template <typename T>
struct add_const_ref
{
    typedef typename boost::conditional
    //      ^^^^^^^^
      <
        boost::is_reference<T>::value, // check if reference
        T,                             // return T if reference
        typename boost::add_reference           // return T const & otherwise
    //  ^^^^^^^^
          <
            typename boost::add_const<T>::type
    //      ^^^^^^^^
          >::type
      >::type
    type;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out and for linking the other thread.